# pivot_wider from only two categories

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr

I have some *long* data, that I could like to *widen*. My initial data Looks lLike this

```
df <- read.table(text = 'Item     Amount   
                          1000    10     
                          1000     1     
                          1500     5     
                          1500     2', 
                 header = TRUE)     
  
library(tidyverse)
```

Now, I would like to *widen* it, using [tidyr](/questions/tagged/tidyr)'s `pivot_wider()`,

```
 df  %>% 
 tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = Item, values_from = Amount)

# A tibble: 1 x 2
  `1000`    `1500`   
  <list>    <list>   
1 <int [2]> <int [2]>
Warning message:
Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
* Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
* Use `values_fn = length` to identify where the duplicates arise
* Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates
```

but I get some error I cannot resolve. What I expected was this, what am I doing wrong? I feel like I am overlooking something essential!

```
#>     # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>       `1000`   `1500` 
#>       <dbl>    <dbl>
#>       10         1
#>        5         2
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't have an identity column to uniquely identify each row, all the values are saved in a single row as a list. You may explicitly pass `values_fn` as `list` and `unnest` all columns to get the data in required structure.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Item, values_from = Amount, values_fn = list) %>%
  unnest(everything())

#  `1000` `1500`
#   <int>  <int>
#1     10      5
#2      1      2
```

If columns can be of different length, create a unique id and then use `pivot_wider`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(rowid = data.table::rowid(Item)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Item, values_from = Amount)
```